# Signature pad for MVC?

Tags: ipad, model-view-controller

I'm creating a MVC project that needs to capture a signature on iPad.

Where can I find resources/controls for a "signature pad" using MVC?

Thanks,
Mojo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick. Its all JavaScript so there shouldnt be a problem using it on an iPad.

http://thomasjbradley.ca/lab/signature-pad

Comment: Thank you for helping me out! .. Doesn't it require FlashCanvas - which is not compatible with iPad?

Comment: I've had a quick look through and it does not seem to requrie FlashCanvas, should be 100% javascript. Take a look at the source of their example : http://thomasjbradley.ca/lab/signature-pad-require-drawn

Answer (score -1):

FYI, It only uses flashcanvas for Windows IE8 and lower, as they do not support the HTML5 canvas element.  It will use the HTML5 canvas element for Firefox, chrome, safari, iPad, other tablet devices, etc.